# Sort a tree view by Many2One field's display name, not ID

Tags: odoo

I do have a list that I want to sort by a field called `hashtag_id` that is a reference to another model.

That other model has a specific/complexe name_get and this is the return of that function that is displayed ot the user and that I do want to sort.  (Note that the result of name_get is not stored in any other column)

View example:

```
<field name="list>
   <tree default_order="hashtag_id">
      <field name="hashtag_id">
```

Data example:

```
ID / result of name_get()
1 / JFOISEZOEIFJF
2 / RZELKRJREZIUH
3 / AERJEIOZJFDOI
```

What the user will see:

```
JFOISEZOEIFJF
RZELKRJREZIUH
AERJEIOZJFDOI
```

What I would like to display (notice the sort done):

```
AERJEIOZJFDOI
JFOISEZOEIFJF
RZELKRJREZIUH
```

**How to make `default_order="hashtag_id"` sort by what's displayed and not by ID ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default order field of `hashtag` model, the order field should be the field used for labeling records, `default: name`:

```
_order = 'name'
```

Or you can add a related field next to `hashtag_id`:

```
hashtag_name = fields.Char(related="hashtag_id.name", store=True)
```

Change the default order to `hashtag_name` and make the field invisible in the tree view:

```
<tree default_order="hashtag_name">
    <field name="hashtag_id"/>
    <field name="hashtag_name" invisible="True"/>
</tree>
```